# LightSwitch HTML : Show Add/Edit screen as Home screen

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, sharepoint-2013

I'm creating a **LightSwitch HTML Application**, where-in I want the Add/Edit screen as the Home screen. I tried setting as a Home screen, but I get only the read only controls. Any ideas?

Thanks and Regards,
Arun Kumar Asirvatham

Answer (score 0):

I think it's by design. If you would like to open the form in Add/Edit mode, you can add a button on top of your form following these steps:

1. In Add button dialog box, choose the Choose an existing method option
2. From Navigation combo box select showCreateNewEntity, where Entity is the entity which is attached to the current screen
3. In the Task list, choose Save

   You can edit these settings in Tap Actions of button property window

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I understand your inputs. Is there any way to show Add/Edit screen as the home screen, without prompting the user to click a button.

Comment: Are you going to use your app on mobile devices? or just thinking about having web user interface without Silverlight?

Comment: I wanted to make use of this app in SharePoint 2013. I prefer to go with LightSwitch HTML.

Comment: you can specify the same tap action as I wrote for the main Tab control which contains data entry controls. that way it looks better

Comment: Ok, got it.. Is there any way to show the add/edit screen without clicking on a button, I mean as a home screen??

Answer (score 0):

What you could do would be to write some javascript to add a new X, and run it when a otherwise blank home screen's .created javscript function is called.

If you want more information just reply